# How do I know which company sponsored which academic conference?

Tags: conference

Is there any easy way to figure out which companies were sponsoring which conferences ?

I mean, in an ideal world, I am looking for such table :

```
Company   | Year  | Conference
-----------------------------
Amazon    | 2021  |  C1,C2
Tweeter   | 2022  | C5,C6
Microsoft | 2018  | C2
```

But, I am not sure, if such thing exist. So, how do you know which company sponsered in which conference ?

Comment: Sponsors are listed on meeting advertisements, abstract books, websites, etc

Answer (score 2):

It is tedious to do it, but if you have a list of conferences you may be able to generate it.

In the modern era conferences tend to have web sites. Many of those sites are long lived. They probably list their sponsors fairly prominently.

For example: http://www.oopsla.org/2005/ShowPage.do?id=Home

A simple google search of conference name and year can turn it up. google: oopsla 2005

---

A custom web crawler could take a list of conference names and years and (at least) turn up the links to those still-existing pages. Parsing the pages for the required information is more challenging, of course.